# Import database structure to database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a purely theoretical question. Is there any possibility to import the .sql database file directly into the database? As you know, a .sql file consists of sequentially generated queries. There are a few of them and I think I would save a lot of code lines. I can cast it structurally, although maybe you are more experienced than me, have some patents for adding the database directly from the .sql file.

Comment: Yes, tools like PhpMyAdmin are capable of this, so it's possible.

Comment: MySQL has import tools which can do this, and GUI tools like Workbench, phpmyAdmin etc make it fairly straightforward. You could easily have googled this.